# How to configure WCF RESTful endpoint for client-side jQuery calls

Tags: wcf-binding

Can some one show me how to configure the WCF Endpoint for the following RESTful Web Service to be called from a JQuery Ajax call. My example service code:

```
    namespace MyService
    {
        [ServiceContract]
        [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
        public class Service
        {
            [OperationContract]
            [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetDepartment")]
            public Department GetDepartment()
            {
                ... code
            };
             return data;
        }
     }
```

jQuery code:

```
         var jData = {};

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: "MyService/GetDepartment",
            data: JSON.stringify(jData),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (jsondata) {
            ... code
         },
         error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following-

```
function SaveBook() {

         var bookData = {};

         $.ajax({
             type: “POST”,
             url: “MyService/GetDepartment″,
             data: JSON.stringify(bookData),
             contentType: “application/json; charset=utf-8″,
             dataType: “json”,
             processData: true,
             success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                 alert(“success…” + data);
             },
             error: function (xhr) {
                 alert(xhr.responseText);
             }
         });
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What I require are the Web.config endpoint configuration settings. Example:

Comment: <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">

Comment: No, the endpoint example fails to resolve the 'Endpoint not found' issue.

Comment: ok, first add "[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]" below your ServiceContract and then run the service on browser like "http://localhost/servicename.svc/GetDepartment", it should work fine.